# Symfony2 deleting acl when deleting a user

Tags: symfony, acl

I want to delete all acl related to a given user after. I found an interesting publication which explains how to do that https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony2/mGTXlTWiMs8/discussion BUT this doesn't clean well.

It deletes entries that match into acl_entries and acl_security_identites and it leaves acl_object_identities. I've looked at my AclProvider.php to find out how to delete object identities through only sid (security identities) but I found nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite old now, but I thought that for the sake of finally having an answer I'd drop my two cents.

It is actually quite simple, as stated in Symfony's documentation, all you have to do is drop the SecurityIdentity, and the cascade rules will ensure that the ACEs will be dropped too.

So the easiest way is to inject the aclProvider in your service :

```
core.services.userListener:
    class: acme\acmeBundle\Listener\UserListener
    arguments: ["@security.acl.provider"]
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener, lazy: true }
```

Then your service will looks like this :

```
<?php
namespace acme\acmeBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Dbal\MutableAclProvider,
    Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Domain\UserSecurityIdentity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use acme\acmeBundle\Entity\User;

class UserListener 
{
    protected $aclProvider;

    public function __construct( MutableAclProvider $aclProvider ){
        $this->aclProvider = $aclProvider;
    }

    public function postRemove( User $user, LifecycleEventArgs $event ) {     
        $securityId = UserSecurityIdentity::fromAccount($user);
        $this->aclProvider->deleteSecurityIdentity( $securityId );
    }
}
```

And now, when you delete the user, the SecurityIdentity gets removed and with it all ACEs linked to it.